# Silverlight play,pause and resume events

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am using silverlight player in our project. It is working well. These days I was loking for silverlight events becasue I will send some information to google analytics on player pause,resume and play events. I checked lots of article. Unfortunately there is no information about these events. All articles give the same example and same events.(onError and onLoad events). How can I add play,pause and resume events in javascript? 
Please check below javascript code.

```
          Silverlight.createObject("XXXXXXXXX",player.get(0),"xxPlayer",
                                  {
                                    width: playerWidth + "", height: playerHeight + "", background: "black"version: "4.0.60310.0",enableHtmlAccess: true'},
                                                       { onError: onSilverlightError, onLoad: null },
                                                       extra, "context");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general purpose `CurrentStateChanged` event which returns the current state of the media (playing, stopped, etc.)

[MediaElement events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement_events(v=vs.95).aspx)

To access the events you need something like this:

```
player = sender.findName("ObjectName");
var stateChangedToken = player.addEventListener("CurrentStateChanged", onCurrentStateChanged);
```

Then you can fill out the `onCurrentStateChanged` JavaScript to do what you want.

[Handling Silverlight events in JavaScript (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189042(v=vs.95).aspx)